# Is there any way to get backlink from disqus commenting system.?

Tags: comments

I have some question suppose if I comment on other blog which don't accept html url .Is there any chance that I will get backlinks for my site if I edit my disqus profile and enter my url.
In short how can I get backlinks for disqus . Withought sapmming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get direct backlinks through using the disqus comment system other than pasting them in the comment content.

As you mentioned you can add your url to your Disqus profile page and each comment you make will link to that page (but with a no-follow link) however the url on the profile is also no-followed so it's hardly a worthwhile way of building backlinks... but it's an extremely good way of getting involved in communities and networking so use it for doing that instead.

In short: You cannot indirectly build backlinks to your chosen url with Disqus.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get a backlink using an anchor text, its simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have read few posts and it said that you get backlink from wordpress site with disqus and the backlink are of nofollow type.. But with other sites having disqus google does not index the comments made on disqus. So you don't get a link.